# Stretch with overflow giving extra space in report

Tags: jasper-reports

I have text box in report Which may extend up to 4000 characters.
I have tried with

> Stretch with over flow = "true"

and i am able to display text with 4000 characters

when i run that in windows its working fine, but if i run the same in Linux machine i am getting some extra space after the text.

as per my knowledge it related to font issue. I have used

> font Name : SansSerif
> PDF font name : Helvetica

I have tried with

> font name : Times new Roman
>
> PDF font Name : Times-Roman

and

> font name :Arial
>
> PDF font name : Helvetica

But no luck!!!

Please find below JRXML for reference.

```
<textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
            <reportElement positionType="Float" x="100" y="94" width="406" height="2"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Top" lineSpacing="Single">
                <font fontName="Arial" size="8" isItalic="false" pdfFontName="Helvetica" isPdfEmbedded="false"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[(($F{flightNotes} == null) || ($F{flightNotes}.length()<= 0))? "No Flight Notes provided for this flight.":$F{flightNotes}.trim()]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
```

In Windows:
[image: In windows]

In Linux:
[image: In Linux]

I am using iReport 3.1.0

Can anyone suggest me which font style will exactly work if textbox having large data using stretch with overflow.

Comment: Did you check both pdf files? Are embedded fonts the same?

Comment: yeah checked and tried with embedded but no luck!!

Comment: Are lists of fonts in both generated *pdf* files identical?

Comment: Alex, Yes it is..

Comment: now i have tested with 'Font Name: courier new' and 'PDF font name: courier'. I am not getting any space but some text is truncating at the end